# IIS hosted WCF with SSL security -"The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'" error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, iis

I am trying to host wcf on IIS, using transport security. I found a good tutorial and follow the instructions : http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/27/wcf-transport-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/. I am always getting "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'". How can I handle it?

What I did so far is:

1. I created self-signed root authority certificate as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms733813(v=vs.110).aspx).

   makecert -n "CN=TempCA" -r -sv TempCA.pvk TempCA.cer
2. Created a new server certificate signed by a root authority certificate

   makecert -sk SignedByCA -iv TempCA.pvk -n "CN=localhost" -ic TempCA.cer localhost.cer -sr localmachine -ss My
3. Created a new client certificate signed by a root authority certificate

   makecert -sk SignedByCA -iv TempCA.pvk -n "CN=clientCert" -ic TempCA.cer clientCert.cer -sr localmachine -ss My
4. Added CA to Trusted Root Certificate

[image]

5. Added these certificates to Personal --> Certificates
   [image]
6. Added client certificate to Trusted People
   [image]
7. Everything looks OK
   [image]
8. Created very simple WCF application. Added it IIS
   [image]
9. Adjust security settings
   [image]
10. This is my service web.config file

> ```
> > <?xml version="1.0"?> <configuration>   <system.web>
> >     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
> >     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
> >     <bindings>
> >       <basicHttpBinding>
> >         <binding name="EmployeeBindingConfig">
> >           <security mode="Transport">
> >             <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
> >           </security>
> >         </binding>
> >       </basicHttpBinding>
> >     </bindings>
> >     <behaviors>
> >       <serviceBehaviors>
> >         <behavior name="EmployeeServiceBehavior">
> >           <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
> >           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
> >           <serviceCredentials>
> >             <clientCertificate>
> >               <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"
> > trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
> >             </clientCertificate>
> >           </serviceCredentials>
> >         </behavior>
> >       </serviceBehaviors>
> >     </behaviors>
> >     <services>
> >       <service
> >         behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeServiceBehavior"
> >         name="WCF.Tutorial.TransportSecurity.ServiceNew.EmployeeService">
> >         <host>
> >           <baseAddresses>
> >             <add baseAddress="https://localhost/WCF.Tutorial.TransportSecurity.ServiceNew"/>
> >           </baseAddresses>
> >         </host>
> >         <endpoint address="EmployeeService"
> >                   binding="basicHttpBinding"
> >                   bindingConfiguration="EmployeeBindingConfig"
> >                   contract="WCF.Tutorial.TransportSecurity.ServiceNew.IEmployeeService"
> > />
> >         <endpoint
> >            address="mex"
> >            binding="mexHttpsBinding"
> >            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
> >       </service>
> >     </services>   </system.serviceModel>   <system.webServer>
> >     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
> ```

11. This is my client app.config

> ```
> >     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> >     <configuration>
> >         <startup> 
> >             <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
> >         </startup>
> >       <system.serviceModel>
> >         <behaviors>
> >           <endpointBehaviors>
> >             <behavior name="EmployeeEndpointBehaviour">
> >               <clientCredentials>
> >                 <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="omer-HP"/>
> >               </clientCredentials>
> >             </behavior>
> >           </endpointBehaviors>
> >         </behaviors>
> >         <bindings>
> >           <basicHttpBinding>
> >             <binding name="EmployeeBindingConfig">
> >               <security mode="Transport">
> >                 <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
> >               </security>
> >             </binding>
> >           </basicHttpBinding>
> >         </bindings>
> >         <client>
> >           <endpoint address="https://localhost/WCF.Tutorial.TransportSecurity.ServiceNew/EmployeeService.svc"
> >                     binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EmployeeBindingConfig"
> >             contract="WCF.Tutorial.TransportSecurity.ServiceNew.IEmployeeService"
> > name="serviceEndpoint"
> > behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeEndpointBehaviour"/>
> >         </client>
> >       </system.serviceModel>
> >     </configuration>
> ```

12. This is my client code and error
    [image]

My question is how can I pass this error? I need your help.

Comment: I couldn't add config files as code snippet. The site did not show the lines so I had to add them as an image.

Comment: The screen captures mean we can't read the text in the pictures (or I can't read them), and we can't search for important text (like `x509FindType=FindBySubjectName`).

Comment: @jww, finally I could add the codes, please review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least, the issue has been found. When I looked inside Windows Event Log I saw that error

> When asking for client authentication, this server sends a list of
> trusted certificate authorities to the client. The client uses this
> list to choose a client certificate that is trusted by the server.
> Currently, this server trusts so many certificate authorities that the
> list has grown too long. This list has thus been truncated. The
> administrator of this machine should review the certificate
> authorities trusted for client authentication and remove those that do
> not really need to be trusted.

I backed some certificates up and deleted them. After this operation my program works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Change the anonymous identity as shown in the IIS Websitee]

Change the anonymous identity as shown in the IIS Website